# How can I assign null to all properties in a type in TS?

Tags: typescript

I want to turn type A into type B how can I do it

```
interface A  {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
}

type B = NullCheck<xxx>;

----> and get

type B =  {
  a: number | null;
  b: boolean | null;
}
```

how should I implement NullCheck

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Comment: To take a guess: You probably have `strictNullChecks` set to `false` which leads to `null` disappearing from the type.

Comment: What do you *want* `NullCheck<xxx>` to be?  Are you saying you want it to be `{a: number | null}` but it's *not*?  Or you're saying it *is* `{a: number | null}` but you don't want it to be?  And if not, what *do* you want it to be?  Help!

Comment: sorry, my description was a bit unclear , I have re-edited my question and I expect to add additional null attributes to each property. Thanks in advance if you can help me again!

Comment: @Rick - the type you had in your original question does exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

Updated:

> I expect to add additional null attributes to each property

### Solution:

```
type NullCheck<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null;
};
```

Your original code was correct. And as others have pointed you, you may have set `strictNullChecks: false` in your `tsconfig.json` file. With `strictNullChecks` turned off, TypeScript ignored `null` and `undefined`.

Try setting `strictNullChecks: true` in your tsconfig file.

Comment: sorry, my description was a bit unclear , I have re-edited my question and I expect to add additional null attributes to each property. Thanks in advance if you can help me again!

Comment: @Rick then, I think your original code was correct.

Comment: No right-hand side `T[P] | null` seems to directly return `T[P]`

Comment: @Rick, make sure you have [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) enabled; in fact, go ahead and enable [the whole `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).